# Regex to match a line that does not have a pattern

Tags: regex, vim

I have a log file in vim that is very big and I want to use regex to search for a pattern: `cell_list <some names>`

There are too many matches with `test` names.

How can I search for `cell_list` lines that do not have any `test` in the line?

```
-I- cell_list {{Xg1 b2a2no2_165}} {{Xg5 xf_134}} I WANT THIS
-I- cell_list {{Xg4 inv_test_150}} {{Xg5 xf_test_142}} DONT WANT THESE
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Vim's flavor of Regex is unlike anything else, but there you go:

```txt
:g/^.*cell_list\%(.*test\)\@!.*$
```

[image: Vim screenshot]

In a more classical, non-Vim flavor for clarity:

```txt
/^.*?cell_list(?!.*test).*$/gm
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/gFGeF2/2

### Explanation

Step-by-step:

- `:g/` — global,
- `^` — asserts position at the start of the line,
- `.` — any single character (other than EOL),
- `*` — match the above zero or more times, greedily,
- `cell_list` — this literal string,
- `\%(` — start of a non-capturing group,

  - `.` — any single character (other than EOL),
  - `*` — match the above zero or more times, greedily,
  - `test` — this literal string,
- `\)` — end of the group,
- `\@!` — negative lookahead assertion (added as a suffix after the group it applies to),
- `.` — any single character (other than EOL),
- `*` — match the above zero or more times, greedily,
- `$` — asserts position at the end of the line.

Also, you may want to see the "Vim Reference Guide" by Sundeep Agarwal for more details:
https://learnbyexample.github.io/vim_reference/Regular-Expressions.html